# Calling SOAP Methods with dots in the name using Python/Suds

Tags: python, soap, suds

Trying to make a SOAP call using Python Suds.  It imports the WSDL fine, and the client it generates looks well-formed, but I am unable to access the methods.

The [Suds documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) describes the method calls like this:

> client.service.Company.GetQueue()

But all I get with every variation of this is:

> suds.MethodNotFound: Method not
>   found:
>   'OmnitureWebService.OmnitureWebServicePort.Company'

Here's the variable dump of the client I have created.  You can see the methods are there, but how do I access them?  I've tried specifying the port, specifying prefixes, nothing seems to work. Thanks for any help with this.

```
> obj._ServiceSelector__client =  Suds (
> https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ ) 
> version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913
> 
> Service ( OmnitureWebService )
> tns="http://www.omniture.com/"   
> Prefixes (2)
>       ns0 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>       ns1 = "http://www.omniture.com/"    Ports (1):
>       (OmnitureWebServicePort)
>          Methods (173):
>             CodeManager.DeleteCodeArchive(xs:int
> archive_id, )
>             CodeManager.GenerateCode(xs:string
> char_set, xs:string code_type, xs:int
> cookie_domain_periods, xs:string
> currency_code, xs:string rsid, xs:int
> secure, )
>             CodeManager.GetCodeArchives(int_array
> archive_id_list, xs:string
> binary_encoding, xs:int
> populate_code_items, )
>             CodeManager.SaveCodeArchive(xs:string
> archive_description, xs:int
> archive_id, xs:string archive_name,
> code_items code, )
>             Company.CancelQueueItem(xs:int qid, )
>             Company.DownloadProduct(productType
> productType, )
>             Company.GetEndpoint(xs:string company,
> )
>             Company.GetQueue()
>             Company.GetReportSuites(string_array
> rs_types, xs:string sp, )
>             Company.GetTokenCount()
>             Company.GetTokenUsage()
>             Company.GetTrackingServer(xs:string
> rsid, )
>             Company.ResetTokenCount(xs:string
> auth_key, )
```

Answer (score 5):

kfed is right, it's the dots that do it.  but I don't want to alter my WSDL.

However, I found this workaround:
Use getattr to reference the method name with a string, get a handle to the method, then call it:

```
Company_GetTokenCount = getattr(client.service, 'Company.GetTokenCount')
Company_GetTokenCount()
```

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/253
Me: Suds version 0.4 GA build: R699-20100913

Comment: wowowow. I have been trying to do this for days. nice find and thanks for posting

Comment: @JiminyCricket Thanks.  I'm hoping kfed accepts this as the answer.  I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it without editing the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Aha.  It looks as if the "." in the namespace, which is proper in XML, but has problems with Suds. I had tried removing, but Suds also caches the WSDL. Here's how to escape:

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/TipsAndTricks

And lower down on the page is how to turn off caching.